# Installing devtools

Tags: r, macos, devtools, ragg

I'm trying to install devtools for R in a MacBook (OS 13.0)

Problem is that it doesn't have dependency pkgdown:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘pkgdown’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/devtools’
```

nor ragg (when I try to install pkgdown)

```
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: 'hb-ft.h' file not found
#include <hb-ft.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘textshaping’


ERROR: dependency ‘ragg’ is not available for package ‘pkgdown’
```

Trying to install textshaping didn't work either, giving:

```
#include <hb-ft.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘textshaping’
* removing ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/textshaping’
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind I solved it with:

```
brew install harfbuzz
brew install fribidi
```

In addition (for future reference) you also need:

```
brew install libgit2
```

and then

```
install.packages("usethis", verbose=TRUE)
```